# apex button to call a page in another application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, permalinks

I have a workspace with which I have 5 applications based on same schema. Now I want to have a main page from where I could call main pages of all these applications. I used this syntax to call home page in another application but to no avail

```
f?p=4000:4150:&APP_SESSION.
```

Where `4000:4150` are the values for the application and the page I want to display.

Please let me know where am I making mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You put the URL in the URL Target field of for example a button.
[image: action when button clicked]

Or in a href field: `<a href="f?p=39957:1:&APP_SESSION.">link to page 1 in other app</a>`

However, note that you will need to authenticate each time you change application. Even though they're using the same authentication scheme, doesn't mean that the authentication stays valid between the apps. When you take note, you'll see the session ids changing.

It is possible to share the authentication though, so you users will only have to log in once. Go to the authentication scheme of an application, and change the cookie name in the session cookie attributes. **Do this in each application you wish to share the session with**.
[image: edit auth scheme]
[image: session cookie attributes]

It seems that your app id and page id look a lot like developer links for your pages. You can't share a session like that though. 
It might even be your issue: if you want to link the user to the page for an application, use the correct ids, and not the developer ids.

Comment: I've got the same problem, I have to link to the developer side. Sadly enough it doesn't work